# AJAX applications Urls and testing with Google Webmaster

Tags: single-page-application, google-search-console

I've been trying to enable web crawling on my Ajax SammyJS site following the information here:
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?hl=iw

and here

http://ajax.rswebanalytics.com/seo-for-ajax/#!sitemap_for_ajax_pages

Both above links appear to hint that I can use the Google Webmaster Tools "Fetch as Google" feature to ensure that my url is transformed from the html tokenised version into the escapedURL format. Whilst I can read the documentation and implement what I believe is correct I could do with some way of testing it.

The below suggests that this not working:

https://www.seroundtable.com/google-fetch-ajax-url-broken-18630.html

So I've got a basic testbed of URLs which I submit in the form:

http://example.com/#!contentPiece1/Test

http://example.com/#!contentpiece2/Test

And I'd like to check that the correct content is displayed in both examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test by rewriting the URL yourself. For example, this URL:

```
http://example.com/#!contentPiece1/Test
```

would become:

```
http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=contentPiece1/Test
```

So if you submit this second URL using "Fetch as Google" and look at the result, you should see the HTML version of the page instead of the Ajax version (assuming you implemented it correctly). You can also test it by typing the rewritten URL directly in a browser and looking at the page source.

It sucks that Fetch as Google is no longer able to rewrite the URL, I hope they get that fixed soon. Googlebot is still rewritting the URLs correctly though, that's the most important part.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that, aware I can test it as you say, just wondered if I could do any integrationg testing with Google. Agree it sucks that they broke the "fetch as google", .